# Getting data from AWS Dynamodb through API Gateway using NodeJS Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm learning to build a API using Amazon Web Services' API Gateway, DynamoDB, and Lambda.

I've been following a video playlist tutorial on Youtube. So far, I've created the desired Lambda Function, DynamoDB Table, and also the API Gateway.

Now all I need to do is build a frontend that display my current items in the table and also the entry.

So far I made it to this part [here](https://youtu.be/mfAT38B_uhw?t=8m3s).

In the video, he uses JavaScript to make an ajax request and fetch the items in the DynamoDB Table. I've written the same ajax request with the html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <h1 style="color:rosybrown;">Latest guestbook entries:</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="entries">

    </div>

    <h1>New Entry</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="msg">Message</label>
        <textarea id="msg"></textarea>

        <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var API_URL = "someURL/prod/entries";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: API_URL,

            success: function(data){
                $("#entries").html("");

                data.Items.forEach(function(guestbookItem){
                    $("#entries").append("<p>"+guestbookItem+"</p>");
                })
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
```

So here I'm going to explain my purpose. The goal is the display the items in the DynamODB table that I have created while also accepting new entries. It has a `date` and `message` item.

The API Gateway has an `/entries` resource and has two methods, `GET` and `POST`. `/prod` means it was deployed on a production stage.

When invoking the URL for the `GET` method. I receive this output

```
"{\"Items\": [{\"date\": 20180512, \"message\": \"this is my 4th message\"}, {\"date\": 20180513, \"message\": \"I love AWS\"}], \"Count\": 2, \"ScannedCount\": 2, \"ResponseMetadata\": {\"RequestId\": \"SOME_REQUEST_ID\", \"HTTPStatusCode\": 200, \"HTTPHeaders\": {\"server\": \"Server\", \"date\": \"Mon, 14 May 2018 20:32:43 GMT\", \"content-type\": \"application/x-amz-json-1.0\", \"content-length\": \"160\", \"connection\": \"keep-alive\", \"x-amzn-requestid\": \"SOME_REQUEST_ID\", \"x-amz-crc32\": \"2401247050\"}, \"RetryAttempts\": 0}}"
```

However, after running the `index.html` file on  my local host.

The entries did not appear. When I checked the console, it turns out I receive the following error

```
index.html:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at Object.success (index.html:33)
at u (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I was not really sure what is going on. `Items` does exist in the response. I've been stuck with this for days. If anybody could point out what I was missing, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you console.log(data) in your success function please? It's been a while since I used jQuery.

Comment: Certainly! it outputs the same as what I get when I invoked the URL for the  `GET` method :) `

Comment: hrm try console.log(JSON.parse(data.Items)) ? It looks like you're getting a string back, you need to turn that into a JS object. although I thought JQ did that.

Comment: So actually you wanna do var theItems = JSON.parse(data.Items);

theItems.forEach.....

Comment: Apparently, I got another error here `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Hrmm without seeing your API it's tough, basically the response you get from your API looks like a string, so you need to JSON.parse(data) to turn that into a JS object.

Comment: Okay, i was able to solve it. Doing `var theItems = JSON.parse(data);` actually solved it

Comment: Ok groovy! So you need to have a read a bit more on this topic, but glad you solved it :-)